# Can javascript from parent page read url of popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

Lets say I'll open a third party page from the parent page using `window.open(popup method)`

Now what I want to know is there any way where the parent page(using javascript or any third party library) which opened the popup can get info back to the parent page

Let's say the popup window loads a particular URL.

I want to grab that URL after it's loaded from that popup to the parent page.
Is that possible?
There is no `content security headers set` in the popup page

and I can't use the popup page in the parent page using iframe
because `X-Frame-Options` Header is set

Is there any other way to get info from the popup page as soon as it loads?

Answer (score 0):

Not for third-party URLs. [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents the parent window from directly getting almost any properties (or most events) of the child window, if the parent and child are not of the same origin. It similarly prevents the child from accessing information about the parent.

However, both parent and child can use [Window messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send data to the other one. This works across origins, though you can and should filter the other origin on both sending and receiving (this is optional); the other origin can be totally unrelated to yours and still work. However, it requires the cooperation of both ends of the communication. Additionally, the communication is push-only; there's no way to extract data that the other end doesn't deliberately send, even if you know the origin of the other window and have already communicated with it deliberately.

If the third-party site cooperates with you, the page you load in the popup can set up window messaging in its onload event or similar, to establish communication immediately.